# MySQL Split String Function SPLIT_STR does not work with LEFT JOIN. Any issue?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, user-defined-functions

Create MySQL Split String Function [`SPLIT_STR` fedecarg.com/.../mysql-split-string-function/](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

Run SQL:

```
SELECT t.en AS `type`, SPLIT_STR(l.en, ',', 1) AS city,
SPLIT_STR(l.en, ',', 2) AS country
FROM table1
JOIN table2
USING ( id )
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t ON table1.type = t.id
/* the next line has failure with SPLIT_STR */
LEFT JOIN table3 AS l ON table1.location = l.id
WHERE language.lang =  'en'
AND language.url =  'europe-countries'
LIMIT 1;
```

table1

```
id               | type            | location
-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
6BC45C02         | place           | london,england
```

table2

```
id               | url
-----------------+-----------------
6BC45C02         | europe-countries
```

table3

```
id               | en
-----------------+-----------------
london           | London
england          | England
```

**Failed result:**

```
type             | city            | country
-----------------+-----------------+----------------
place            | NULL            | NULL
```

**Expected result would be to return `city` and `country`:**

```
type             | city            | country
-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
place            | London          | England
```

---

On checking if `SPLIT_STR` is working with simple SQL:

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR(location, ',', 1) AS city, SPLIT_STR(location, ',', 2) AS contry
FROM table1
WHERE id =  '6BC45C02'
LIMIT 1;
```

it returns fine result:

```
city             | contry
-----------------+-----------------
london           | england
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting the results?, what happens if you change your current `SELECT` to this `SELECT t.en AS [type], l.en`?

Comment: Also (but not the real problem), you should change `SPLIT_STR(l.en, ',', 1) AS country` to `SPLIT_STR(l.en, ',', 2) AS country`

Comment: The left join in some cases will result in null values that your function is not handling.   But worse unless your example is messed up, Table1.type value 'Place' <> table3.id value 'london' so you're getting nulls.  the problem continues with the table3 as l join as value 'london,england' <> 'london' or 'england'  you should ahve a 2 as well on the select for country.

Comment: Also, the join that you are doing on table3 doesn't make any sense, `id` and `en` are the same. And you are applying your split on the `en` field, but that field has the values splitted already

Comment: @Lamak - `SELECT t.en AS [type], l.en` would not work. And thanks for mentioning `SPLIT_STR(l.en, ',', 2) AS country` in the question - I updated it.

Comment: @Lamak - `table3` column `id` and `en` queries are different and might be different. I have posted just an simplified example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this... but performance will be terrible.

```
SELECT T1.type,
  SPLIT_STR(t.en, ',', 1) AS city,
  SPLIT_STR(l.en, ',', 2) AS country
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
  ON T1.ID = T2.ID
LEFT JOIN table3 t 
  ON t.id = SPLIT_STR(t1.location, ',', 1)
LEFT JOIN table3 l 
  ON l.id = SPLIT_STR(t1.location, ',', 2)
WHERE t2.url = 'europe-countries'
LIMIT 1;
```

This would be better as it doesn't require calling the function 4 times: (used coalesce to determine if function isn't working as expected will return proper case, then lower case, then function broke if it's not working as expected)

```
SELECT InTable.Type, 
   coalesce(t.en, inTable.City, 'FunctionBroke') as city, 
   coalesce(l.en, intable.country, 'FunctionBroke2') as country
FROM 
    (SELECT t1.type,
      SPLIT_STR(T1.Location, ',', 1) AS City,
      SPLIT_STR(T1.Location, ',', 2) AS Country
    FROM table1 T1
    INNER JOIN table2 T2 
      ON T1.ID = T2.ID 
        AND t2.url='europe-countries'
    ) InTable
LEFT JOIN table3 t 
  ON InTable.City = t.id
LEFT join table3 l 
  ON InTable.Country = l.id
LIMIT 1;
```

Still better exists: is table 3's only purpose to Proper case the city/country name; and is the only purpose of the UDF (user defined function) to split the values?

- EDIT 1 Fixed first should have been t.en instead of l.en on first left
  join.
- EDIT 2 Fixed 2nd should have been t1 (that's copy and paste for
  you)
- EDIT 3 Relooked at everything in both responses copied several of the errors in the OP

Comment: For your second SQL I get error `#1054 - Unknown column 'l.en' in 'field list'`.

Comment: Your first updated SQL returns query just for `type`=>place, for `city` and `country` returns NULL.

Comment: Thanks, xQbert! Your first SQL (Query took 0.0011 sec) returns `type`:place, `city`:London and **empty query for `country`**. The second SQL (Query took 0.0009 sec) works fine and returns expected result `type`:place, `city`:London and `country`:England.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, `SPLIT_STR(l.en, ',', 1)` will always be `null` (there is nothing to split in `table3.en`) Also, joining  condition for table `table1.location = l.id` always false for your data (neither `london` nor `england` equals to `london,england`).

Based on desired output you posted, I think you are looking for something like (I'm not sure what is `language.url =  'europe-countries'` , I don't see table or alias named "language" in the question, so I just ignored it)

```
SELECT t1.`type` AS `type`, 
MAX(CASE WHEN t3.id = SPLIT_STR(t1.location, ',', 1) THEN t3.en END) as `city`,
MAX(CASE WHEN t3.id = SPLIT_STR(t1.location, ',', 2) THEN t3.en END) as `country`
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id)
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON 
 (t3.id = SPLIT_STR(t1.location, ',', 1) OR t3.id = SPLIT_STR(t1.location, ',', 2))
GROUP BY t1.`type`
```

**Updated** (l.en replaced by `t1.location`)

Comment: It returns an error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id) LEFT JOIN table3 t' at line 4`.

Comment: going to have similar problems I am l.en is not an aliased table name.

Comment: sorry for misprint, extra comma after `country`  ... Fixing

Comment: I also forgot closing round bracket in `LEFT JOIN` condition... Fixed.

Comment: Your latest updated SQL returns error `#1054 - Unknown column 'l.en' in 'field list'`.

Comment: I replace `GROUP BY t1.[type]` with `WHERE t2.url = 'europe-countries'` and it now returns the expected result. Your SQL query takes 0.0010 sec. It is slower than @xQbert second SQL.

Comment: I think `group by` should be there. Regardless of `WHERE`